# Is there any way to determine the *actual* session save path?

Tags: php, session

I know there are half a dozen ways to get the value of the `session.save_path` directive (`phpinfo()`, `session_save_path()`, etc.), but when the value is an empty string, as it is by default, the actual path can be any of several locations. I've read that it's usually `/tmp`, except when it's `/var/lib/php5`, but on OS X Mountain Lion it's definitely `/private/var/tmp`. On Windows, it's probably `C:\Windows\Temp`, but who knows.

I could specify the location, but that won't really help me. I'm trying to diagnose a tricky problem and I would like to know what the current location is on a server that I don't have full access to. If there's a right way to do it, I haven't been able to find it. I'm open to clever hacks.

Comment: I'd assume PHP would use the temp folder when the `save_path` is blank.  You could try using [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php).

Comment: That's a theory I hadn't considered, but unfortunately it's wrong. When I run `php -r 'echo sys_get_temp_dir();'` from the command line (OS X 10.8.4), I get `/var/folders/_k/...`.

Comment: Actually, your test is wrong.  Temp folders can vary per-user.  If I run that from the command line in OSX I get a similar path, but that's irrelevant because the server doesn't run under my user account.  Printing `sys_get_temp_dir()` from a test page that goes through Apache gives me `/var/tmp`, which does contains the session file.

Comment: @PeterGeer You're right. My bad, Rocket Hazmat. I wrote a quick script to list the contents of the temp folder on the server and it's full of PHP session files.

Comment: If this resolved the issue please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not reviewed the PHP source code to confirm this, but it looks like when `session.save_path` is empty, PHP uses the value of `sys_get_temp_dir()` (which varies by user).