# Location of session files in Apache/PHP in OS X?

Tags: php, apache, session

I'm following a set of instructions for setting up Apache/PHP on CentOS, but I'm using OS X, so I'm trying to find the correct equivalents. It tells me to set the `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"`. However, that folder doesn't seem to exist on OS X. There is no PHP folder inside lib.

The default `session.save_path` was set to `/tmp`, and I'm not sure where that it is located on the file system. Any clarification on this would be appreciated as well. Is there an equivalent to `/var/lib/php/session` on OS X?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to determine the \*actual\* session save path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109685/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-actual-session-save-path)

Answer (score 3):

[`session_save_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)  returns the path of the current directory used to save session data.

Comment: `session_save_path()` may return an empty string..   full answer:  `session_save_path() ?: sys_get_temp_dir()`  (ie if `session_save_path()` is empty, use `sys_get_temp_dir()`)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your `php.ini` file.

By default, the path is set to `tmp` folder, on macOS:

```
echo $TMPDIR
```

will give you this path.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer of [Nadjib KHELIFATI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909223/nadjib-khelifati)

You can execute this command in the terminal:

```
php -r 'echo "PHP Sessions PATH: ".((session_save_path()) ? session_save_path():sys_get_temp_dir() ).PHP_EOL;'
```

Or add the line to a php file

```
<?php

echo "PHP Sessions PATH: ".((session_save_path()) ? session_save_path():sys_get_temp_dir() ).PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to store the PHP file into the www folder to call it from the browser?
If that is the case I believe it is `/var/www/html/`